# Parse error in pattern: xs - understanding

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, parse-error

i have the following two functions in haskell:

```
plusList :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
plusList [xs ys] = add xs + plusList [ys]
plusList [[]] = 0


add::[Int] -> Int
add (x:xs) = x + add xs
add [] = 0
```

so, i think i have the error in plusList [xs ys] = add xs + plusList ys

My idea was to go through the set of the sets, namely [[Int]], by taking the first List xs, apply "add" on it and after that, call the second list ys recursively with "plusList ys"

I am new in haskell, can I do that? And if no, why?

Answer (score 10):

You can certainly do what you want in Haskell, but your syntax is wrong.  Your `add` function is correct, but `plusList` is not.  In particular, the syntax `[xs ys]` makes no sense as a pattern to Haskell, you probably want

```
plusList (xs:ys) = add xs + plusList ys
```

Notice how this is exactly the same pattern as with `add`?  Although, from your type signature it's hard to tell what exactly you want.  The type says return a list of `Int`, but your function body says to just return an `Int`.  If you want the former, you can achieve it with

```
plusList (xs:ys) = add xs : plusList ys
```

But this is exactly `map add`!  If instead you want the latter, use the first snippet from above.

The second problem you have is

```
plusList [[]] = 0
```

This is a perfectly valid and legal line of Haskell code, but it won't do what you want.  You see, there's a difference between `[] :: [[Int]]` and `[[]] :: [[Int]]`.  The first is an empty list of lists of `Int`s, the second is a list containing an empty lists of `Int`s.  If you run `length ([] :: [[Int]])`, you'll get `0`, but for `length ([[]] :: [[Int]])` you'll get 1!.  Instead, just do

```
plusList [] = 0
```

Again, this is exactly like the pattern in `add`.  If you want `plusList` to return `[Int]` instead, this line should just be

```
plusList [] = []
```

So the two versions we have are

```
plusList :: [[Int]] -> Int
plusList (xs:ys) = add xs + plusList ys
plusList [] = 0
```

And

```
plusList :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
plusList (xs:ys) = add xs : plusList ys
plusList [] = []
-- or just
-- plusList xs = map add xs
```

---

There is an easier way to do this, though.  Firstly, `add` is merely the built-in `sum` function but specialized to `Int`s.  However, the built-in `sum` is not very efficient due to the fact that it uses `foldl`.  Instead, you can implement a faster variant with

```
add :: [Int] -> [Int]
add xs = foldr (+) 0 xs
```

The `foldr` and `foldl` functions generalize the kind of recursion you have used, since it is such a common pattern in functional programming.  Instead of operating on the entire list, you provide a function for combining the next value and an accumulator together, an initial accumulator value, and the values to accumulate.  In your case, the accumulator has the same type as your values, which is pretty common.  The difference between `foldl` and `foldr` is subtle, their implementations look pretty similar, but Haskell's laziness means that `foldl` can have space leaks and efficiency problems (there's plenty of explanations out there as to why, look it up when you get there).

Additionally, if you want to sum a list of lists, you can do it using higher order functions with simply

```
plusList = add . map add
```

Nothing extra is needed, no patterns to match, much less syntax to get wrong.

Comment: I think you are mixing up `foldr` and `foldl'`.  `foldr` here would still have a space leak, although with just stack space instead of thunk building (followed by stack once the thunk runs), I think.